# Toilet does not produce enough water and barely flushes

Tags: toilet

My toilet takes two flushes to flush and does not produce enough water. Any helpful tips to help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Check the water level in the tank. Watch the tank water while flushing. Does the tank fill within a few inches of the top? How low does the tank get at the low point of the flushing cycle? Is the flapper over the hole in the bottom of the tank closing too soon? When flush, does water go into the vertical tube that feeds the toilet's rim holes? Do the rim holes release any water (from under the bowl rim) during the flush? There are all kinds of floats for cutting off water flow at the end of flush. Does your float appear to be working as it should?

Comment: You may have the fill adjustment set too low (the water in the tank should come to just below the vertical tube that the small tubing clips to).  It may also have a flapper that provides two flush levels -- a quick flush for liquid waste and a longer flush for solid waste, or it may have an adjustment for how long it stays open that is factory preset for your convenience to a water-saver setting.

Comment: As fixer1234 says, it might be that your flapper is closing to quickly, what happens if you hold down the handle for longer?  Also, in order for us to best help you can you tell us what other things you've tried to fix this, or why this is suddenly a problem (and wasn't when the plumber installed it)?